# criar div em tempo de execução

Tags: jquery, html, html5

tenho o seguinte html:

```
 <div>
    <h3>Use font awesome icons</h3>
    <div id="lobipanel-font-awesome" class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="panel-title">
                Panel title
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet concealed leaf shah proper council binary. Concealed assured affairs faces, finish easily glows shouted faint. Sentence islands spouting we unbeguiled, faces concealed. Diam rays countries, faces fames peeling bind wary catch solomon, painting, they beats evil. Failing newer landscapes steal retinues vidi rays echoes sheltered evil. Veins concealed spouting obtaining delight wild. Venenatis failing wreaths shouted countries wild, privilege climbing.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

esse codigo gera um painel, na pagina tem um botao "abrir painel", gostaria que o painel fosse criado (aberto) depois de clicar no botao, como posso fazer isso? tem como gerar o html em tempo de execução?

Comment: Não sei bem o estilo que quer atingir mas já pensou em usar o elemento <details> ? Pode dar o mesmo efeito que quer além de dar semantica para seu html. link: http://html5doctor.com/the-details-and-summary-elements/

Answer (score 1):

**- JavaScript**
**- Css**
**- Html**

```js
$( "#Clique" ).click(function() {
  $("#escondido").css("display","block");
});
```

```css
#escondido{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Botão -->
<a href="http://google.com.br" target="_blank" id="Clique">Clique aqui</a>
<!-- Div oculta -->
<div id="escondido">
    <h3>Use font awesome icons</h3>
    <div id="lobipanel-font-awesome" class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="panel-title">
                Panel title
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet concealed leaf shah proper council binary. Concealed assured affairs faces, finish easily glows shouted faint. Sentence islands spouting we unbeguiled, faces concealed. Diam rays countries, faces fames peeling bind wary catch solomon, painting, they beats evil. Failing newer landscapes steal retinues vidi rays echoes sheltered evil. Veins concealed spouting obtaining delight wild. Venenatis failing wreaths shouted countries wild, privilege climbing.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

ou você pode adicionar o código com o javascript:

```js
$( "#Clique, #botao" ).click(function() {
  var html = '';
  html += '<div id="escondido">';
    html += '<h3>Use font awesome icons</h3>';
      html += '<div id="lobipanel-font-awesome" class="panel panel-info">';
        html += '<div class="panel-heading">';
          html += '<div class="panel-title">';
            html += 'Panel title';
          html += '</div>';
        html += '</div>';
        html += '<div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet concealed leaf shah proper council binary. Concealed assured affairs faces, finish easily glows shouted faint. Sentence islands spouting we unbeguiled, faces concealed. Diam rays countries, faces fames peeling bind wary catch solomon, painting, they beats evil. Failing newer landscapes steal retinues vidi rays echoes sheltered evil. Veins concealed spouting obtaining delight wild. Venenatis failing wreaths shouted countries wild, privilege climbing.';
      html += '</div>';
    html += '</div>';
  html += '</div>';

  $("#painel").html(html);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Link -->
<a href="http://google.com.br" target="_blank" id="Clique">Clique aqui</a>
<!-- Ou button -->
<button id="botao">Botao</button>

<!-- Div onde ficara o conteudo -->
<div id="painel">
</div>
```